# c atoi() for wide chars on linux?

Tags: c, linux, atoi

Is there a c atoi() equivalent for wide chars on Linux? I can find something for MS (wtoi) but I can find anything in a standard Linux lib.

Comment: where do you get wide characters from on linux? What encoding? Wouldn't you just convert to UTF-8?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [wcstol](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-of-Integers.html) to convert from wide strings to integer values.

Answer (score 8):

It is unusual for a Linux program to use `wchar_t` type.

The reason being that Linux uses utf-8 as the standard encoding. `char const*` strings are assumed to be utf-8 strings by glibc. Ascii digits and utf-8 digits have the same byte representation, so that atoi() works both on ascii and utf-8 strings.

Having said that, look in `#include <wchar.t>`, it provides [`wcstol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wcstol.html).