# atoi() with other languages

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, internationalization

I am working on a internationalization project. Do other languages, such as Arabic or Chinese,  use different representations for digits besides 0-9?  If so, are there versions of atoi() that will account for these other representations?

I should add that I am mainly concerned with parsing input from the user.  If the users types in some other representation I want to be sure that I recognize it as a number and treat it accordingly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068972/c-atoi-for-wide-chars-on-linux

Comment: Should explain on the link: Whether the use of `wchar_t` makes sense on your system or not depends on what kind of encoding you're using; for UTF-8, the usual `strtol()` / `atoi()` would do, but if you've got multi-byte/constant-size character sets they won't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may use `std::wistringstream` and locale to generate this integer.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  locale mylocale("en-EN"); // Construct locale object with the user's default preferences
  wistringstream wss(L"1");  // your number string
  wss.imbue( mylocale );    // Imbue that locale
  int target_int = 0;
  wss >> target_int;
  return 0;
}
```

[More info on stream class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36h875af%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [on locale class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w3527e2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 for a Standard solution, although it's highly dependent on the C locales available on the system.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about international characters, then you need to ensure you use an "Unicode-aware" function such as _wtoi(..).

You can also check if UNICODE is supported to make it type independent (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
TCHAR tstr[4] = TEXT("137");

#ifdef UNICODE
size_t cCharsConverted;
CHAR strTmp[SIZE]; // SIZE equals (2*(sizeof(tstr)+1)). This ensures enough
                   // room for the multibyte characters if they are two 
                   // bytes long and a terminating null character. See Security 
                   // Alert below. 

wcstombs_s(&cCharsConverted, strTmp, sizeof(strTmp), (const wchar_t *)tstr, sizeof(strTmp));
num = atoi(strTmp);

#else

int num = atoi(tstr);

#endif
```

> In this example, the standard C
>   library function wcstombs translates
>   Unicode to ASCII. The example relies
>   on the fact that the digits 0 through
>   9 can always be translated from
>   Unicode to ASCII, even if some of the
>   surrounding text cannot. The atoi
>   function stops at any character that
>   is not a digit.
>
> Your application can use the National
>   Language Support (NLS) LCMapString
>   function to process text that includes
>   the native digits provided for some of
>   the scripts in Unicode.
>
> Caution  Using the wcstombs function
>   incorrectly can compromise the
>   security of your application. Make
>   sure that the application buffer for
>   the string of 8-bit characters is at
>   least of size 2*(char_length +1),
>   where char_length represents the
>   length of the Unicode string. This
>   restriction is made because, with
>   double-byte character sets (DBCSs),
>   each Unicode character can be mapped
>   to two consecutive 8-bit characters.
>   If the buffer does not hold the entire
>   string, the result string is not
>   null-terminated, posing a security
>   risk. For more information about
>   application security, see Security
>   Considerations: International
>   Features.

Comment: I think Visual C++ has some built in macros that do most of this switching for you.